# Problems in the use of sum. TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum, tuples

I get an error when adding two values 5 and 5. I would like to receive result 10. I wrote the code based on tuples, this brought me some previous errors because it cannot be add, for example,

```
sum_A = sum (count_A)
```

because I received an error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'

So i solved it with `sum(int(row[0])` for the row in `count_gol_fact_home_sqA`. I didn't like it very much this way. I don't want to use sum_A = sum (int (row [0]) for row in count_A)

However I continued, but I ran into an error that does not make me add sum_A and sum_B.

How can I add `sum_A` and sum_B? Is there another way to more easily write my code by previously adding `sum_A = sum (count_A)` without receiving errors?

```
#ELEMENT 1
cursor.execute('SELECT City FROM Nation WHERE X = ?', [X])
count_A = cursor.fetchall() #Print [(2,), (1,), (2,)]

sum_A = sum(int(row[0]) for row in count_A) #print 5
print(sum_A)
###########################################

#ELEMENT 2
cursor.execute('SELECT City FROM Nation WHERE Y = ?', [Y])
count_B = cursor.fetchall() #Print [(3,), (2,)]

sum_B = sum(int(row[0]) for row in count_B) #print 5
print(sum_B)
###########################################

SumA_B = sum(sum_A, sum_B) 
print(SumA_B) #ERROR: I would like to get result 10
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    SumA_B = sum(sum_A, sum_B)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Why should you do this in code ? If its an integer in database, cant you aggregate it in query itself ?

Comment: @Kris Yes, it is an integer in the database. How to do?

Comment: Change your query like `SELECT SUM(City) FROM Nation WHERE X =...` , that should return the sum from server itself. Result from multiple queries will be a normal integer addition further!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, to fix the error, your problem is that [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) sums the elements of an iterable - ***not*** a variable amount of arguments passed to it. So you need to change it to an iterable, like:

```
sum((sum_A, sum_B))
```

Or if you only have two items, why not just `count_A + count_B`?

---

Then, to simplify your `sum`s, you could use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) or the more convenient [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) which are used to flatten 2D lists (like you have):

```
from itertools import chain

sum_A = sum(chain(*count_A))
# Or:
sum_A = sum(chain.from_iterable(count_A))
```

---

Lastly, you don't even need to sum A and B separately and sum again the result. Just concatenate them and sum at once:

```
total_sum = sum(chain.from_iterable(count_A + count_B))
```

Or, in spirit of chaining, you can avoid creating a new list (when doing `count_A + count_B`) by chaining all the tuples, after chaining the two lists:

```
total_sum = sum(chain.from_iterable(chain(count_A, count_B)))
```

Comment: Thanks. Later I read carefully and answer. I'm not home now

Comment: Nice answer yours. Thanks. I had never used iteration before. I am new to Python. But if I wanted to simplify things and never use an iterable, what could I do? So what if I wanted to add without using an iterable? Could you show me the code example of my question without the interable? So getting 5, 5 and then 10 without iterables? It's very important for me. Thanks

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean... A list is an iterable. You are summing a list. How can you not use iterables?

Comment: I'm talking about "sum". Can I add the elements contained in a list or a tuple without using "sum" but using something else? Thing? Like? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use a loop and add each value to a counting variable, but why would you do that if you have a built-in function that already does it for you?

Comment: Being new to python I asked myself: is it better to use "sum" which is iterable or to use a loop and add each value to a counting variable? Is using the "sum" intregate function the right choice in these cases?

Comment: Of course. Why wouldn't it be. You can do everything by hand using loops and basic operators. But why not simplify the code by using built-in functions that are there to help us...

Comment: Being new, I cannot vote yet. I don't have the reputation yet. I have set up your answer as a solution to the question. In a few days, when I have more users, I will vote for your answer. Don't worry I don't forget. Thank you very much for helping

Answer (score 0):

`sum` expects an iterable, use:

```
SumA_B = sum([sum_A, sum_B])
```

Comment: Everything is OK now. What if I wanted to change the sum_A = sum (int (row [0]) for row in count_A) piece of code? So if I wanted to replace it with sum_A = sum (count_A). If I write sum_A = sum (count_A), I get an error (TypeError: unsupported operand type (s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'). Because? How to solve?

Comment: It's difficult to answer question of the type *"how do I do <something incorrect>"* ;) better explain what you expect to achieve, provide an example of input and the expected output. Maybe look into `itertool.chain.from_iterable`

Comment: The inputs are count_A = cursor.fetchall () #Print [(2,), (1,), (2,)] and count_B = cursor.fetchall () #Print [(3,), (2,)]. I would first like to add them both to get 5 and 5, and then I would like to get the output 10 (5 + 5)

Comment: Then what's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: I wrote it in the question. I didn't really like it that way. I don't want to use sum_A = sum (int (row [0]) for the row in count_A). I would use sum_A = sum (count_A) or something similar, but got this error: TypeError: unsupported operand types for +: 'int' and 'tuple'

Comment: Then, as I said, check `itertools.chain.from_iterable` ;)

Comment: Being a newbie in Python, can you suggest me an answer of how I can do? Thank you